# Using a local variable as a param in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm having trouble with this. I have three models connected here: Users, Listings, and Pseudonyms. Essentially, a User can upload books to sell, but they can also create Pseudonyms in case they want to list a book under a different name.

This works great on the Listing show page. I am using this in the controller.

```
@pseudo = Pseudonym.find(@listing.pseudo_id)
```

Then on the show page I simply use `<%= @pseudo.name %>` to display the pseudonym.

Here is the controller for both actions.

```
def index
  @pseudo = Pseudonym.find_by(params[:pseudo_id])
  @listings = Listing.all.order
end

def show
  @pseudo = Pseudonym.find(@listing.pseudo_id)
end
```

For context, my pseudonyms table simply stores the name, id, and the user id who created it.

```
  create_table "pseudonyms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_pseudonyms_on_user_id"
  end
```

When a user creates a new listing, they select the pseudonym from a dropdown of all their pseudonyms.

new listing form

```
<%= f.collection_select(:pseudo_id, current_user.pseudonyms, :id, :name, prompt: 'Select a pseudonym if you want to use one. Ignore this to use your real name.') %>
```

My problem is when I need to display the pseudonyms on any index page. When I iterate through all the listings, I no longer have access to `@listing.pseudo_id`.

```
<% @listings.each do |listing| %>
    <li>
        <%= link_to listing do %>
            <%= image_tag listing.image.url(:thumb), title: listing.title %>
        <% end %>

        <div class="listing_overview">          
            <h2><%= link_to truncate(listing.title, length: 24, separator: ' '), listing_path(listing) %></h2>

            <div id="stars">
                <div class="star-rating" data-score=<%= listing.avg_rating %> style="max-width: 10%; margin-0;"></div>
            </div>

            <%= image_tag(listing.user.image.url, title: listing.user.username) %>

            <% if listing.pseudo_id? %>
                <%= link_to @pseudo.name, user_path(listing.user) %></p>
            <% else %>
                <%= link_to listing.user.name, user_path(listing.user) %></p>
            <% end %>
            <b><%= number_to_currency(listing.price) %></b>
        </div>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

It works, however, on the index page the wrong pseudonym is being displayed. If a user only has one pseudonym in the database, it's fine. But any user with more than one, it will display the first one they created. It is not finding the pseudonym by the id, which needs to be from `listing.pseudo_id`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you change `@pseudo = Pseudonym.find_by(params[:pseudo_id])` to `@pseudo = Pseudonym.find(params[:pseudo_id])` in your `index` action?

Comment: Yeah now I just get an error. `Couldn't find Pseudonym with 'id'=`. The pseudonyms are saving fine to the listings table as well, because they show up on the show page. Just on the index page, they all show as the earliest created by that user.

Comment: I would assume you're sending the pseudonym in the parameters of the request `params[:pseudo_id]`? and in the case no pseudonyms are in the request, you'd need to have a guard for the case the user ir not using a pseudonym

Comment: I have no idea what I'm sending, or what I'm doing for that matter. :) As for the second part, I have it in the view to ask if there is one, if not it displays the user's real name.

Comment: Could you add this line: `puts "===Pseudonym ID requested = [#{params[:pseudo_id]}]"` right before this: `@pseudo = Pseudonym.find_by(params[:pseudo_id])` in your controller to see actually if you're sending a pseudonym to the controller, request the index page in your application and check the logs?

Comment: This showed up in my terminal. `===Pseudonym ID requested = []
  Pseudonym Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "pseudonyms".* FROM "pseudonyms" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]`

Comment: And that's why it cannot be found, your index method is relying in an id being present in the request but there is none. Before it was working because you're using `find_by`: like: `Pseudonym.find_by("")` which returns the first one it finds ... you can try it in the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176739/discussion-between-ddonche-and-alex-unger).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to get this to work. My problem was I was making it complicated by thinking I could do the controller params the same way as link_to routes. For example, one might use

```
<%= link_to "Some Page", some_page_path(page.id) %>
```

I thought I could pass the local variable from the listings loop back to the controller. Ultimately, I ended up just making each listing belongs_to a pseudonym.

listing.rb

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :pseudonym, optional: true
```

pseudonym.rb

```
class Pseudonym < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :listings
```

I deleted the pseudo_id column from the listings table and simply added a foreign key to reference the pseudonyms table.

```
class AddPseudonymsToListings < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :listings, :pseudonym, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Now, there is no reason to bring up anything in the controller. Because this column is optional, there may be times when this column is nil, so in the view I specify only to display the pseudonym if the pseudonym id is present, otherwise display the user's name. I simply call the pseudonym from the view like so:

```
<% if listing.pseudonym_id? %>
    <%= link_to listing.pseudonym.name, user_path(listing.user) %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to listing.user.name, user_path(listing.user) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If users can define multiple pseudonyms try checking whether the listing has any pseudonym:

```
listing.pseudonyms.any?
```

and if so, iterate over them

```
listing.pseudonyms.each {|pseudonym| ... }
```

Comment: Each pseudonym is stored in the pseudonym table, so only one pseudonym can be picked when you make a new listing. So it's stored in the listing's pseudo_id column. I thought it would be simple to link them that way.

Comment: then you want to make sure the most recent gets pulled out of the database, right?

Comment: try: `@listings = Listing.all.order('created_at DESC')`. Another issue I see here is that you'd sort ALL the listing every time, it might impact performance

Comment: No, in the listings form, they can choose from a dropdown list of all the available pseudonyms to populate the pseudo_id. I will update the question to show that.